# adding current_user to a comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

EDIT: I've created a new model in my rails app where users can comment on a guideline.  I'd like it to automatically allocate the current_user to be the commenter.  I am having real problems with working out how to allocate 'commenter' (with or without it being current_user).  I am now completely confused about attributes and relationships and I would very much appreciate if someone could help

As it stands with the code below - I can't seem to allocate anything as commenter.  I can create a new comment (body) but cannot seem to be able to allocate the commenter at all (its value is 'nil)

comments_controller.rb

```
 def create
            @guideline = Guideline.find(params[:guideline_id])
            @comment = @guideline.comments.create params[:comment].merge(commenter: current_user)
            redirect_to guideline_path(@guideline)
        end
```

comment.rb (model)

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :guideline
 belongs_to :commenter, class_name: 'User'
 belongs_to :user

  attr_accessible :body, :commenter
    end
```

guideline.rb (model)

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :favourite_guidelines
has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
```

the db migration has

```
create_table :comments do |t|
      t.string :commenter
      t.text :body
      t.references :guideline

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :comments, :guideline_id
```

my _form has

```
<%= f.input :commenter %>
<%= f.input :body, label: 'Comment', as: :text, :input_html => { :cols => 200, :rows => 3 } %>
```

Comment: how is user associated to a comment?

Comment: You should also change that to `has_many :comments, :foreign_key => 'commenter_id'` after deleting the `belongs_to :user` association.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your commenter attribute is a string, that won't work. Change your migration to this:

```
create_table :comments do |t|
  t.references :commenter
  # ...
end
```

Also, remove the `belongs_to :user` bit from your Comment model, add `:commenter_id` instead of `:commenter` to your attr_accessible and change the way you create a comment:

```
@comment = @guideline.comments.build params[:comment].merge(commenter_id: current_user.id)
@comment.save
```

After these changes, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :current_user_makes_the_comment

  private
    def current_user_makes_the_comment
      self.user_id = current_user.id
    end
end
```

or try with the `current_user.build` syntax and pass the `guideline_id` in the `create` method

Comment: would this trigger mass assignment security exception?

Comment: this wouldn't work because `current_user` is not accessible in the model

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following association

```
# comment.rb
belongs_to :commenter, class_name: 'User'
```

try

```
# controller
@comment = @guideline.comments.create params[:comment].merge(commenter_id: current_user.id)
```

Comment: have changed things as edited above (i removed the _id parts because there was no commenter_id attribute) and I get undefined method `active_admin_config=' for CommentsController:Class

Comment: ignore the message about active_admin, I resolved this. when edited as above (as per you but without the id).  the comments are not being added properly this way.  They are appearing on my view as being added but when I look in the console for the guideline - comments are 'nil' and so comments.commenter is nil too

Comment: if a comment belongs to a user, you also need to add commenter_id to attr_accessible

Comment: ok I have done that and it is showing in my console with a comment.  But the commenter is still empty

Comment: if I try with the _id parts in as you originally said I get ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute: commenter_id):
  app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:5:in `create'

Comment: that's why I asked what the association is between a comment and a user.  does comment belong to a user? if it does, how do you define the association?

Comment: no, I didn't have comment belonging to a user.  I have now added belongs_to :user

Comment: so that means you have a user_id column in your comments table. change commenter_id to user_id in the code above.

Comment: thanks for helping me.  I don't think I do have a user_id column in my comments table. I guess I should add this?

Comment: it just has t.string :commenter
      t.text :body
      t.references :guideline

Comment: ok you need to add a foreign key to associate the comment to the user.  you can add a `user_id` which is an integer to comments and add the `belongs_to :user` association to comments